# Which Java collection allows cheap appending?

Tags: java, list

I am searching for a list data structure in Java which allows cheap appending of long lists. I tried LinkedList but I found in the documentation of [addAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29), that an iterator is used to append the two lists. This means that the list, which gets appended, gets cloned during the operation. The iterator walks though the whole list returning every single element. Is there any collection available which omits the iteration while appending two lists?

Comment: You mean you want structure sharing between the lists?

Comment: I'm no expert in Java, but I don't think that fits the Java collections API, so you'll want to look for third-party libraries (or roll your own).

Comment: This question is related to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237308/merge-two-lists-in-constant-time-in-java, there is no analogue to STL's list::splice method in any of JDK collections

Comment: If the resultant list needs to be read-only, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4896662/100836

Comment: @Zaki: Hmmm this is the second time I hit [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). The first time I was able to solve the problem without requiring Guava. But this time it seems to be hard.

Comment: @bobah: Oh my question seems to be a dup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Guava's](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [Iterables.concat](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable%29) method to create concatenated Iterable View..

```
Iterable<T> combined = Iterables.concat(list1, list2);
```

- This **does not copy elements** from one list to another..
- So, it **does not change** any of your lists..
- Also, **this does not create** a new list (It creates an `Iterable` which is not a list)

Basically it creates an `Iterable` through which you can iterate over the `two` lists back to back (It iterates elements from list1 then from list2..

**NOTE**: -  **If you want a list** as a concatenation of the `two lists`, then this might not help you much.. Because, it does not create a list, but an Iterable.. For that case, you have no other choice than `Iterating` over your lists and `copy` each of your reference..

From the [docs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable%29): -

> It Combines two iterables into a single iterable. The returned iterable
>   has an  iterator that traverses the elements in a, followed by the
>   elements in b.  The source iterators are not polled until necessary.
>   The returned iterable's iterator supports remove() when the
>   corresponding  input iterator supports it.

You also have a **`var-args` version** of this method.. [See Docs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat%28java.lang.Iterable%29).. This can take any number of lists, and returns Iterables that can iterate over those lists in order.. So, you can do like this..

```
Iterable<T> combined = Iterables.concat(list1, list2, list3, list4, ...);
```

This link --> [google-guava-libraries-essentials](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/google-guava-libraries-essentials.html) might also be of interest to you..

Comment: indeed faster... is it O(n)? It has to find the end of one list

Comment: Indeed this is even faster. It does not have to find the end.. It already has the tow lists.. Concatenation is O(1)..

Comment: You can also combine `multiple` lists using this approach.. See Var-arg version of this method: - http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat(java.lang.Iterable...)

Comment: Is it really necessary to use Guava? It sounds strange to me that the standard libraries of Java do not provide such a simple functionality. Even [Glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Singly-Linked-Lists.html#g-slist-concat) has it.

Comment: @ceving.. Well they do provide.. They have `addAll` methods, and they have many more methods to work with multiple collections.. But jsut to make these operations more efficient, Third party libraries are created.. Else they won't even exists.. You can easily use them, and get your work done..

Comment: @ceving.. Another example of Third-Party library is [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), which makes your life easier like heaven when it comes t working with Date.. And it might also get integrated with Java 8..

Comment: @ceving.. And that is something new you have given me.. `GLib`.. Wasn't aware of that.. Thanks :)

Comment: Its is worth nothing that an `Iterable` is not a "list data structure". To turn it into one you would have to copy all the elements so it doesn't really save you anything.

Comment: @PeterLawrey.. Yeah that thing I have added as one of my 3 points in my post.. It does not create a new list.. It is just helpful, if you want to iterate over multiple lists..

Comment: @RohitJain I use a nested loop to iterate over multiple lists, but I am not as "functional" as I could be. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey.. Well, if what all one want is a new list containing all items from the two lists, then iterating over them through nested loop is the best bet we can have.. :)

Comment: @PeterLawrey.. But if number of lists increases, that will drive you Crazy.. won't it.. ;)

Comment: If your lists are not too big though, because of cache locality, you will probably be worse off than just copying. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4XkWSAm2XU

Answer (score 5):

Not really, since all "append" operations don't make any assumptions about the underlying collections. Technically two linked lists could be appended directly, but the append has to be generic so it uses iteration.

Another good reason to not allow direct concatenation is the fact that after the append changing one list will also affect the other, which I'm sure is not a desirable property.

Comment: Is there any other way to go with the standard libraries?

Comment: @ceving: You could subclass `LinkedList` and provide your own implementation I guess.

Answer (score 4):

[addAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) in ArrayList converts it to an Array and then uses a system call to copy ([System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)). This should be quicker than looping through in java as it is native, I dont think there is a cheap appender.

Comment: Don't think so. It does not make much difference if the length of the list is long enough.

Answer (score 3):

May be addAll of ArrayList should be quicker because it doesn't iterate , but use System.arrayCopy.The code looks like

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    Object[] a = c.toArray();
        int numNew = a.length;
    ensureCapacity(size + numNew);  // Increments modCount
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, elementData, size, numNew);
        size += numNew;
    return numNew != 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> This means that the list, which gets appended, gets cloned during the operation.

Creating an iterator doesn't clone the collection.

The addAll method in most cases calls toArray() to ensure the data is extracted atomically which clones the elements of the collection as an array and this is likely to use an Iterator to do it.

> Is there any collection available which omits the iteration while appending two lists?

No, but you can iterate the collection yourself if this is *really* important.

---

The most efficient is likely to be

```
List<E> list1 = ... random access list ...
List<E> list2 = ... random access list ...

for(int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++)
    list1.add(list2.get(i));
```

This doesn't create any objects and has `O(n)` time where `n` is the size of list2.

Comment: I don't want to iterate and I don't want to copy.

Comment: You have to copy the references at a minimum. You can do that with a loop.

Comment: @ceving 'don't want *this* and don't want *that*' :) So *what* do you really want to achieve?

Comment: @Durandal: Fast concatenation. And fast means: no copy and no loop.

Comment: The only way to do that would be to create a custom List which is a view on the two original Lists. It can be done but gets increasingly complicated with more than two lists.

Comment: @ceving You have to chose between *no copy/loop* and *concatination*. As multiple answers already explained you can't have both with a *List*. You can wish for it, but don't expect reality to oblige :)

Comment: Sorry this is quibble. Rohit Jain gave the correct answer: Java is not able to do it and it is necessary to use a third library like Guava.

Comment: @ceving Its worth nothing that an Iterable is not a `list data structure` and to turning it into one requires copying every reference.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you do find such a collection class you couldn't be guaranteed that it will continue to work that way in future versions of Java.  That's because this is a behavior that's not specified in the Collection interface and is therefore subject to the whim of the class developer.

You could, of course, write your own collection class, but even then you'd be making assumptions about the behavior of other Collection classes

Answer (score 0):

Default implementation of `addAll` method in `AbstractCollections` uses iterator to add **but `addAll` method is overridden in sub classes which provides custom specific implementation**

Like

- ArrayList uses `System.arraycopy`
- LinkedList uses a Loop to traverse through elements.

Comment: Yes I know. I am looking the the third one, which neither copys nor loops.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way with the standard API, but depending on your needs you would try to implement one by yourself.  For example, you can implement one which internally has a List of collection references, added every time you call the addAll method.

Answer (score 0):

with that behavior the list added to the first list will get consumed (i.e. modified) or results in the second list becoming a sublist of the bigger one with all kinds of gotchas (like what happens if you add a list twice...),

the addAll has an implicit const argument (meaning that the second list will remain unmodified over several calls), so this behavior won't exist unless you roll your own

Answer (score 0):

I would simply take ArrayList, and happily addAll() my stuff to it. It doesn't really matter how the chosen List implementation performs the addAll() operation, iteration or toArray are both relatively cheap and its very unlikely this will be a performance bottleneck (that assuming your application *does* useful work with the list elements and not just create lists...).

There is really no way around the iteration in addAll(), if you want an independent list that contains the elements from N source lists, the element references *have* to be copied somewhere (you could change the source lists after addAll(), but that must not affect the conactinated list, thus a copy is unavoidable).

If you do not really *need* the List semantics (independend of the sources), then make use of the already suggested Guava to create a *view* of multiple lists (or roll your own, its not rocket science if you don't want the dependency).